# Save viewstate in a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I've problem with a user control in asp.net

I've created a usercontrol that save a value in the viewstate, now the problem is that on postback the viewstate loses this value

Why? Should I do something in particular?

If necessary tonight I'll load some code.

Comment: Did you do any research on this?  There are many posts already out there that address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

May be this is because  ViewState is disabled on a parent control.Check that you don't have `EnableViewState=false` anywhere because that would prevent you to retrieve the value on the page postback.

Comment: I checked EnableViewState in the main page and in the user control and in either case is setted to True